# What happens if rules are applied multiple time to a form

Tags: jquery, html

This is more of a generic question, please remove it if this is not a correct platform.

My question is what happens if rules are applied to html form multiple time. like every time user clicks on button if rules are applied what will be the impact.

I am pretty sure such things won't happen but in case if we do that will browser go for a memory leak.?

Below is a sample validaiton.

```
    $("#fromValidate").validate({
                rules: {
                    txtName: { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    txtName: { required: "Please Enter Name." }
                },
                ignore: []
            });
```

If above rules are called everytime user clicks the button what will be the impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is quite simple, it will run, validate, and exit. No memory will be used, apart from the first time the button is clicked and the validation method is being set.

If you would store those validation rules in an array and append to that array every time the button is clicked, the memory will fill. But that is not the case.

Even if that would be the case, these functions seem so simple you won't run into problems. This is pretty safe.

Comment: Thanks Randy, As of now I am applying this rule every time user clicks on a hyperlink. click of hyperlink will open a new partial view which is already present in page but it is display off. However after this validation code, Chrome has become v v slow.. So i was suscepting whether this is culprit.

Comment: It could be that this method would slow your process down, but that has nothing to do with memory. More with CPU power. Check if you are running those two methods async or not, and if it is browser-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the jQuery validate plugin. It will just rerun your specified validation settings and repaint information. As you're not calling any serverside validation or sending requests but just iterating the DOM, there won't be any memory leak.